# Css li elements inside ul

Tags: html, css

I am developing website and I have a problem,

`<li>` elements aren't inside `<ul>`

[image]

```css
#category_select {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  height: 50%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#category_select li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="category_select">
  <li>Naslovnica</li>
  <li>Elektronika</li>
  <li>Bijela tehnika</li>
  <li>Vozila</li>
  <li>Sport</li>
  <li>Dom i vrt</li>
  <li>Odjeća i obuća</li>
  <li>Moda</li>
  <li>Literatura</li>
  <li>Ručni radovi</li>
  <li>Igračke</li>
  <li>O nama</li>
  <li>Kontakt</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you put some more detail about what you are trying to do?

Comment: i try to make css menu so li elements must be inside ul

Comment: They are inside the UL element?

Comment: but look at ul border and li elements

Comment: Try removing `height:50%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
#category_select li {
    display: inline-block; //change display:inline to display:inline-block
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/7gjcL0uq/4/)